# How would I stop a if loop after execute one time?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```py
if len(columns) > 0:
    #print "IF LOOP"
    for index in range(len(columns)):
          txt = columns[index]
          msg = msg + txt + '  Declared'
    msg = ' '.join(msg.split())
    notifier(msg)
```

I created one cronjob in my program but i want to stop execute this loop after one time.

Suppose i create new variable in starting and after one time execute this loop assign `False` so if loop checks two conditions if Variable is `False` so it will not execute this statement....

but every time cronjob creates new objects so what is the solution for this to stop execute this statement in if loop after one time executed.

Comment: If you want to stop the *for* loop after one time - why are you looping at all ?

Comment: You can use **break** anytime inside the loop to leave it

Comment: Why not just write `for txt in columns:`?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`break`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#break) if you want to exit a loop (either `while` or `for`). A very simple example:

```
count = 0

for _ in range(1000):
    count += 1
    if count == 1:
        break
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but it will not work because cronjob creates new objects means again build this program so again in startin count= 0
so that executes loop statements.
i want to execute loop statement only once after again i run that program it would not execute those statemens.